# How to check if a username is already taken?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, cs50

I need to check the username input in a registration form using javascript along with flask in python but I don't know how to implement it.

I have to use `$.get` in the javascript part and in the python code which should check and return a jsonifyied true or false.

Python code:

```
@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
def check():
    """Return true if username available, else false, in JSON format"""
username = request.args.get("q")
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=username)
if len(rows) >= 1 or len(username) < 1:
    return jsonify(False)
else:
    return jsonify(True)
```

HTML part:

```
<form action="/register" method="post" id ="register">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="confirmation" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submittion" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
    <script>
       let input = document.querySelector('input[name=username]');
       input.onkeyup = function() {
            $.get('/check?q=' + input.value, function(data) {
                if (data == "FALSE"){
                    data.preventDefault()
                    alert("Username is not available!");
                }
            });
        };
    </script>
```

It should alert the user if the username already exists once it is checked in the SQL. The debug shows it does search through the list for the username but it doesn't alert or anything.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Just so you know, this is a site to which you bring problems in your code you have spent a long time trying to solve and **as a last resort** had to ask for help with. This is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a true/false value. In JavaScript this value will not be a string in which you are testing against:

```
if (data == "FALSE")
```

By testing against an actual boolean, you should get your desired result:

```
if (data == false)
```

or

```
if (!data)
```

Comment: thanks but it still does not respond or show anything. it should search automatically as soon as I write a username that exists and respond

Comment: could you please provide the data that gets returned

Comment: It is possible that you are getting an error, because `data.preventDefault()` doesn't exist on the returned json. Also, you should add a 3rd parameter to `$.get`, as it might not know that it is a json value.

Comment: wrong data... You can find the data in the browser network tab. `F12 -> Network`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should write it as following:

```
@app.route("/check", methods=["GET"])
def check(username):
    """Return true if username available, else false, in JSON format"""
username = request.args.get("q")
rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username", username=username)
if len(username) < 1:
    return jsonify(False), 400
if len(rows) < 1:
    return jsonify(False), 400
else:
    return jsonify(True), 200
```

and in javascript:

```
if (data == "FALSE")
```

to

```
if (data[1] == false)
```